# Where to host a medium-sized web app in Vue.js and Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, google-app-engine, web-applications, hosting

I'm building a web app and I would like to host it online but I am completely new to this.
I made some research and found out that I have a bunch of different, as well as confusing, options:

1. Professional hosting service
2. Dedicated server (too expensive right now)
3. Virtual private server
4. Cloud services (e.g. Google Cloud Platform)

What I need is a reliable and **scalable** place to host my app. Something that is free or cheap at first (**50€/month maximum**) but **I should also be able to upgrade it** as soon as the number of users start growing.

Provided that I use:

1. Vue.js for frontend
2. Django for backend
3. PostgreSQL as DBMS

Is the Google App Engine a good option for me? How much would it cost per month? I tried using Google Cloud Platform pricing calculator but I need a lot of information of which I'm totally ignorant (e.g. istances per hour or number of cores per hour)
If you think that Google App Engine isn't good for what I need what are your suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) is the solution for you. It's easy to deploy, scalable and it's free on the beginning.